# On a converse of a real-line generalization of Lipschitz condition

Tags: real-analysis

For $A \subseteq\mathbb R$ let $A:=\{x-y \in \mathbb R : x,y \in A\}$ If $f : A \to \mathbb R$ is uniformly continuous on $A$ , where $0$ is a limit point of $A-A$ , then is it true that there is a function $g:A-A \to \mathbb R$ with $\lim _{x \to 0}g(x)=0$ such that $|f(x)-f(u)|\le g(x-u),\forall x,u \in A$ ?

(I can prove the converse that is :  Let $ A \subseteq \mathbb R$ be such that  $0$ is a limit point of $A-A$. If $f : A \to \mathbb R$ and $g:A-A \to \mathbb R$ are such that   $\lim _{x \to 0}g(x)=0$ and $|f(x)-f(u)|\le g(x-u),\forall x,u \in A$ , then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $A$ )

Comment: When you put {curly braces} _outside_ of the math-notation environment, you introduce mismatches in font and infelicitous spacing.  I changed it.  Just use backslashes: if you type \{x-y\in\mathbb R\}, you'll see $\{x-y\in\mathbb R\}$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

Define, for every $t\in A-A$,
$$g(t)=\sup\left\{|f(x)-f(x')|:x,x'\in A, |x-x'|\leq |t|\right\},$$
so we have a function $g:A-A\to\mathbb{R}$.

First, let's show that $\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)=0$: Let $\varepsilon>0$. Since $f$ is uniformly continuous, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that  whenever $x,x'\in A$ and $|x-x'|\leq\delta$, we have $|f(x)-f(x')|\leq\varepsilon$. If $|t|<\delta$, then we have, for any two elements $x,x'\in A$ with $|x-x'|\leq|t|$, that $|f(x)-f(x')|\leq\varepsilon$. Since $g(t)$ is the supremum of those values $|f(x)-f(x')|$, then $|g(t)|=g(t)\leq\varepsilon$.

This shows that $\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)=0$.

Now, suppose $x,u\in A$, and let $t=x-u$. Notice that $|x-u|\leq|t|$ (trivially), and thus, by definition of $g$, we obtain $|f(x)-f(u)|\leq g(t)=g(x-u)$.

Comment: It's not clear , elaborate please

Comment: @SouvikDey Ok. I added all the details I could think of.

Comment: but what gurantees that we can find $x,x' \in A$ such that  $|x-x'|\le |t|$ , where $|t| < \delta $ ?

Comment: @SouvikDey By assumption, $0$ is a limit point of $A$. Alternatively, why not take $x=x'$?